# Why does my conditional jquery script only work once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I can click on the `tr` and it will check the checkbox. Then, I can click on the `tr` a second time and it will uncheck the checkbox. However, if I try to click the same `tr` a third time (or greater), then the script no longer works. I have tried several versions of this script using `prop()` instead of ``attr(), but it still exhibits the same behavior. Why?

HTML:

```
<tr onclick="checkBox('ID')" id="recordID">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myRecords[]" id="myRecordsID" value="ID">
    </td>
</tr>
```

jquery:

```
function checkBox(ID) {
    $(document).on("click",'#record'+ID,function(){
        $(document).on("click",'input#myRecords'+ID,function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        var ischecked = $('input#myRecords'+ID).is(":checked");
        if(ischecked) {
            $('input#myRecords'+ID).removeAttr("checked");
        } else {
            $('input#myRecords'+ID).attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem stems from two things:

1. having nested listeners
2. a permanent false positive

HTML:

```
<tr id="recordID"> <!-- remove the onclick, you are already listening for it -->
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myRecords[]" id="myRecordsID" value="ID" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

jquery:

```
function checkBox(ID) {
    // move this listener outside so it does not require a click to activate
    $(document).on("click",'input#myRecords'+ID, function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on("click",'#record'+ID,function(){
        var ischecked = $('input#myRecords'+ID).is(":checked");
        if(ischecked) {
            // use .prop, while your method will check and uncheck the box
            // it will not work properly with jquery's .is(":checked");
            // eventually resulting in a permanent false positive
            $('input#myRecords'+ID).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('input#myRecords'+ID).prop('checked', true)
        }
    });
};
checkBox('ID'); // activates listeners
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/K8L57/

---

If I was writing this http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/3qped/

HTML:

```
<tr class="record">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myRecords[]" value="ID" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.record').on('click',function(){
    var checkBox = $(this).find('input');
    checkBox.prop('checked', !checkBox.prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't binding events within the function cause them to be bound every time the function is executed?

Comment: Yes. But the function is only being executed once.

Comment: You call the function, but what this person wants is to transfer the ID to the function. That does not happen this way.

Comment: @Fresheyeball What makes you think it's only being executed once?   The user had previously stated that they have a problem executing it multiple times.. so it stands to reason that they want to be able to execute it multiple times.

Comment: @Daedalus I know its being executed once in my version because it does not have nested listeners.

Comment: @Daniel he can still do so.

Comment: @Fresheyeball - Yes, it can, but the initial call in the code of the question implies that the ID is passed forward from the table row that is clicked. You would have to find the correct ID within the function `checkBox(ID)`.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Not exactly what I meant.  In your version you only execute it once, however the OP implies they are going to be executing it multiple times.

Comment: @Daniel, no reason to find it inside the function, its passed as an argument.

Comment: @Daedalus in re-reading the OP's question, he does not imply this function is going to be called multiple times, he says he is 'clicking' multiple times.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Why would one click multiple times if that was not their intended action.  I would say that is a good implication.  If it doesn't work more than once, and only once is intended, what would the problem be?

Comment: @Fresheyeball - Adding a row would carry a different "id". You are passing a string to the function and hence it will only work on the row with that id. It works, but is not functional in a multiple-row table. I would love to give teh credits, but I must insist. I adapted your example to multiple row-> http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/K8L57/1/

Comment: @Daedalus dude. seriously. The OP is clicking multiple times, not running the function multiple times. The reason it WAS running multiple times is because he had nested listeners. My answer demonstrates this principle.

Comment: @Daniel the OP had a function that accepted an ID portion as a string.  I fixed that function, but yes he still has to pass the portion as a string. If you want a multiple-row as one function version, I have that too as my second answer.

Comment: @Fresheyeball ..  The function is running multiple times because it is bound in inline-html, present in the OP's question.  Clicking multiple times, in this instance would run the function multiple times.

Comment: @Daedalus I REMOVED IT FROM THE INLINE ELEMENT AND COMMENTED IT. Its literally the first thing in the code for my answer.

Comment: @Daedalus in other words, my answer does not have nested listeners.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Shouting is not needed.. and that is not my point.  My point, is that this user's actions demonstrate that running they would be running the function multiple times...  However, I see that I misread your answer, though even then I would fall to Daniel's point, in that the 'ID' present in the test case could only be used in that particular instance, so such is not optimal.  Though I also see you accounted for that, so +1.

Comment: @Fresheyeball The incivility is not needed, I guess I wasn't clear in my retraction.  I did read your answer in the first place, though as _previously stated_, I **misread it**.

Comment: @Daedalus I apologize. I just got frustrated.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Thank you, accepted, and I am sorry for being frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

There is nested code and I wonder if the way you apply the on() jquery function is correct.

It can be simplified to this:

```
   <table>
    <tr id="recordID12" class="myRecordEntry">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myRecords[]" id="myRecordsID12" value="ID">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="recordID15" class="myRecordEntry">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myRecords[]" id="myRecordsID15" value="ID">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myRecordEntry").click(function (e) {
        var id = e.currentTarget.id;
        var idnr = id.match(/\d+/g);
        var chk = $("#myRecordsID" + idnr).is(":checked");
        if (chk == false) {
            $("#myRecordsID" + idnr).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("#myRecordsID" + idnr).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/p8Sr8/4/

**edit:**
What you want is likely to generate multiple rows with your record collection and therefor the table rows may have a different ID. I have made the code adaptable to suit this need.